# Lower bound for a power series with coefficients as difference between values from a periodic function

Tags: sequences-and-series, absolute-value, estimation, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose $f(x) = |x|$ for $x \in [-1,1]$ with a periodic extension $f(x+2) = f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. We are given the property that for any x, either: $|f(x+h) - f(x)| = h$ or $|f(x-h) - f(x)| = h$ for $0\leq h \leq \frac{1}{2}$. For $h_k = \frac{1}{2}4^{-k}$, this gives us the property
\begin{align*}
|f(4^n (x+h)) - f(4^n x) |=
\begin{cases}
0 \quad n>k\\
4^n |h| \quad n\leq k
\end{cases}.
\end{align*}

Suppose we have the series $g(x) = \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n f(4^n x)$. We are asked to prove the lower bound for $\left|\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}\right| \geq \frac{3^k + 1}{2}$ using $h=h_k$ or $h=-h_k$.

Attempt:
Since the tail terms of $g(x+h) - g(x)$ go to $0$ then we have
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}\right| = \left|\sum \limits_{n=0}^{k}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n \left(f(4^n (x+h)) - f(4^n x)\right) \right|.
\end{align*}

I am thinking to apply the result $|x-y|\geq |x| - |y|$ for some choice of term in the summation but this is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Edited the equation for better formatting

Comment: @user10354138 the standard triangle inequality would give an upper bound though? or did you mean the reverse variant I outlined as $|x-y| \geq |x| - |y|$? If it's the latter, I'm just not sure what the choice of x should be. Even though a largest term should exist in the summation, getting an explicit formula seems impossible

Comment: Apply triangle inequality in the form $\lvert a+\sum b_i\rvert\geq\lvert a\rvert-\sum\lvert b_i\rvert$.

Comment: That's a good idea and similar to the reverse triange inequality outlined. What would be a good choice for a though?

Comment: You know the magnitude of all terms, so just choose the largest one.

Comment: @user10354138 I'm just not sure there's an explicit formula for the largest term which can give the bound. I'm sure it's something I'm just not seeing but could you please elaborate on a precise form for the largest?

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\tag{1}
\left(\frac34\right)^n\left\lvert f(4^n(x+h))-f(4^nx)\right\rvert\leq\left(\frac34\right)^n4^n\lvert h\rvert=3^n\lvert h\rvert
$$
and equality is achieved for at least one choice of sign of $h$, $\lvert h\rvert\leq h_n$.

So we have
\begin{align*}
\left\lvert\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}\right\rvert
&=\left\lvert\frac1h\sum_{n=0}^k\left(\frac34\right)^n\Big(f(4^n(x+h))-f(4^nx)\Big)\right\rvert\\
&\geq 3^k-\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}3^n\\
&=3^k-\frac{3^k-1}{3-1}=\frac{3^k+1}{2}.
\end{align*}
where $h=h_k$ or $h=-h_k$ is chosen so we have equality in (1) with $n=k$.